# Beginning Turkish reading/listening resources

Tags: resource-request, turkic-languages

I have been working through the lessons on TurkishClass101 and Duolingo, but I would love to find resources for learning Turkish from Turkish sources. Are there any famous kids shows or books that would be appropriate for someone who has just started learning? Or podcasts that are catered towards beginners?

I'm particularly interested in resources where I can practice reading, writing or listening.

Something like [DemTurkishCenter](http://www.demturkishcenter.com/turkish-books-fairy-tales-1/) sounds perfect, but I'd prefer to exhaust free resources first if that's an option.

Answer (score 2):

I am maintaining a [list of free listening resources for various languages](https://www.notion.so/hb20007/Free-Language-Exposure-Resources-b0c94219bdd1498e855a8d04a4287155).

For Turkish, I have a list of TV series, movies, TED talks, and short films with English subtitles. These can be helpful to practice listening.

If you are looking for something catered toward beginners, then I recommend [Easy Turkish](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1U-NW0ci6d1aHLc2gOHv8Q) on YouTube. The concept is interviews with people on the streets of Turkey on various interesting topics, and they provide subtitles in both Turkish and English.

Answer (score 1):

For reading: clozemaster (or its source tatoeba).
For listening: Maybe children series like Pepee on Youtube.

Comment: I second the recommendation of Clozemaster. If you're able to do the fill-in-the-blank exercises (not multiple choice) I recommend doing that. If the multiple choice is too hard, you can start with Cloze-listening until it's accessible to do the fill-in-the-blank. I find fill-in-the-blank not only helps me more with word recall, but also helps me learn spelling, which improves writing skill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for, just in case if you're or someone else ends up there here some resource videos;

[Learn Turkish with Turkishaholic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQYWGEOKno4&list=PLt4ygjU3XRvaTDqSSRcxK3XKqWc3IJUS3)
[A video compliation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr84WInwkdo&list=PLOcHm2I6dWq1TavVJq5HL6BHmEuP2NxJq)